# problem with adding custome font and pdf-lib

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf

I am trying to use pdf-lib to create and edit pdf files.
Imported libraries as static resources, source code from here
https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js

https://unpkg.com/@pdf-lib/fontkit@1.1.1/dist/fontkit.umd.js

Some examples with rendering or adding an image work fine, but failed to import custom font, throws an error
[image]

Examples taken from https://pdf-lib.js.org/
I can't figure out the source of the error and how to fix it

```
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import pdflib from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdflib";
import fontkit from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/fontkit";

    renderedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, pdflib).then(() => {});
    loadScript(this, fontkit).then(() => {});
}
```

this work fine

```
    async createPdf() {
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    const timesRomanFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(PDFLib.StandardFonts.TimesRoman);

    const page = pdfDoc.addPage();
    const { width, height } = page.getSize();
    const fontSize = 30;
    page.drawText("Learning with Salesforce Bolt !", {
        x: 50,
        y: height - 4 * fontSize,
        size: fontSize,
        font: timesRomanFont,
        color: PDFLib.rgb(0, 0.53, 0.71)
    });

    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    const stampedPDF = await pdfDoc.save();
    const tempblob = new Blob([stampedPDF], {
         type: "application/pdf"
    });
    this.showPDF = URL.createObjectURL(tempblob);
}
```

this don't

```
async incomeStamp() {
    try {
        const url = "https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf";
        const fontBytes = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
        console.log("ubuntu fonts loaded");
        const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create()

        console.log("doc created");
        pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
        console.log("kit registered");
        const ubuntuFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes);
        console.log("ubuntu fonts embedded");

        return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce supports only these fonts,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-
us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm

if you would want custom loaded font then it requires a third party library

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/242/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf

Page 76

**Visualforce PDF Rendering Considerations and Limitations**

Review these considerations and limitations when designing Visualforce pages intended to be rendered to PDF. Always verify the
formatting and appearance of the PDF version of your page before putting it into production.

Limitations of the Visualforce PDF rendering service include the following.
• PDF is the only supported rendering service.
• The PDF rendering service renders PDF version 1.4 and CSS versions up to 2.1.
• Rendering a Visualforce page as a PDF file is intended for pages designed and optimized for print.
• A Visualforce page rendered as a PDF file displays either in the browser or is downloaded, depending on the browser’s settings.
Specific behavior depends on the browser, version, and user settings, and is outside the control of Visualforce.
• The PDF rendering service renders the markup and data on your page, but it might not render formatting contained within the
contents of rich text area fields added to the page.
• Long lines of text that don’t have break points, such as a space or dash, can’t be wrapped by the PDF rendering service. This scenario
most commonly happens with long URLs, registry entries, and so on. When these lines are wider than the page, they increase the
width of the page’s content beyond the edge of the PDF page. Content then “flows” off the side of the page and is cut off.
• Don’t use standard components that aren’t easily formatted for print, or form elements such as inputs or buttons, or any component
that requires JavaScript to be formatted.
• PDF rendering doesn’t support JavaScript-rendered content.
• PDF rendering isn’t supported for pages in the Salesforce mobile app

Answer (score 0):

When you import external JS in LWC. After loading JS methods are available under the window object.

I see in your code you're not getting the Libraries using window.PDFLib or window.fontkit.

```
let pdflib =  window.PDFLib;
let fontkitV =  window.fontkit;
```

If you are still not able to run the methods you could check if the libraries are loaded or not

```
loadScript(this, pdflib).then(() => {

console.log('loaded');
console.log(window.PDFLib);
}).catch(error=>{
console.log(error);
})
```